# Why is my JavaScript code refusing to run on my website?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following is what my HTML document looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/homepage-script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="how-it-works">
    <p>How It Works</p>
    <img src="some-imageurl">
    <div id="steps">
    <p>Step 1</p>
    <p>Step 2</p>
    <p>Step 3</p>
</div>
```

And here is my script:

```
$('#steps > p').on('click' , function(){
    $('steps > p').css('background', 'yellow');
});​
```

Why is my script not running on my website?

Comment: you are missing the `#` sign in your second selector....

Comment: Because you're running it before the DOM is ready? https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the jQuery in a document ready and you can use $(this) since it is targetted in the onclick event:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#steps > p').on('click',function(){
          $(this).css('background', 'yellow');
    });​
})
```

however what I would recommend is having a highlight class that is then toggled in the onclick event;

```
//CSS
.highlight{background:yellow}


$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#steps > p').on('click',function(){
          $(this).toggleClass('highlight');
    });​
})
```

Tht way you are adding / removing a class instead of altering the elements CSS.

If you want to add the highlight class to all the p's in that div as per @Phil comment -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#steps > p').on('click',function(){
         $('#steps > p').toggleClass('highlight');
    });​
})
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#steps > p').on('click',function(){
          $(this).toggleClass('highlight');
    });
})
```

```css
.highlight{background:yellow}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/homepage-script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="how-it-works">
    <p>How It Works</p>
    <img src="some-imageurl">
    <div id="steps">
    <p>Step 1</p>
    <p>Step 2</p>
    <p>Step 3</p>
</div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: How do you know OP doesn't want to turn **all** the paragraphs yellow?

Comment: That's jquery. not javascript.

Comment: @sara err, what? jQuery is JavaScript

Comment: @sara - three points - a) the OP indicates a tag of jquery, b) the OP is including the jQuery library and c) the OP's script IS JQUERY!

Comment: never mind ...  :)

Comment: I tried the code in the first code block and for some reason it isn't displaying.

Comment: I just added your html my my answer together in the snippet and it works fine - clicking the p colors the background yellow - clicking it again removes the background color. Try running my answer in the code snippet

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `#` selector in your nested line of code:

`$('#steps > p').css('background', 'yellow');`

This will make *all* of the `p` elements turn to a yellow background. If you only want the element the user clicked, then reference the "selected" object with `$(this)`:

```
$('#steps > p').on('click' , function(){
    $(this).css('background', 'yellow');
});
```

Comment: Still won't work as the script runs before the elements are present

Answer (score 0):

The script should be after the div.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="how-it-works">
    <p>How It Works</p>
    <img src="some-imageurl">
    <div id="steps">
    <p>Step 1</p>
    <p>Step 2</p>
    <p>Step 3</p>
</div>

<!--The script should be after the div.-->
<script src="scripts/homepage-script.js"></script>
```